# Laravel returning empty collection even if the records exist

Tags: php, laravel

The following is the Model class

```
namespace App\Models\BaseModels;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BallByBall extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'ball_data';
    protected $primaryKey = 'trans_id';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

The schema of `ball_data` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `ball_data` (
  `trans_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_trans_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `match_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `innings` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batsman_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batsman_id2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bowler_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fielder_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batsman_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bowler_given` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_runs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_runs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_runs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `for_wicket` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ball_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ball_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ball_type` varchar(573) DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_no` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `maiden` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wicket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wicket_type` varchar(573) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wicket_desc` varchar(573) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ball_length_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ball_area_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `power_play` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(573) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commentry` varchar(573) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`trans_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5025 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I execute `App\Models\BaseModels\BallByBall::get();` I receive an empty collection.

Comment: Can you show your table definition?

Comment: show us the browser result!

Comment: I had manually created the database. and following is its schema.

Comment: If records exist and you've correctly defined your model according to the database table and not all of the records have been soft deleted then you should receive some entries in the collection. That means that one of the above is not true.

Comment: Please update the question with the results of the following 2 queries: `DESCRIBE ball_data;` and `SELECT * FROM ball_data LIMIT 5;`.

Comment: Thank You All for the help, It was bcoz of the deleted_at column getting set to current timestamp by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `SoftDeletes` trait and it looks like you have a timestamp in `deleted_at` column instead of `null` for this record. This means this record is soft deleted and Laravel won't show it by default.

So, use the [`withTrashed()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting) method to include all soft deleted rows as well:

```
BallByBall::withTrashed()->get()
```

Or change `deleted_at` to `null` for this record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use something to get soft deleted records like ->withTrashed() function. Then is it possible to get() or all() the collection.